# How to partition based on the month and year in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am going to use ADF to copy 5 billion rows to Azure SQL data warehouse. Azure SQL DWH will distribute the table into 60 distributions by default, But I want to add another 50 partitions based on the month and year as follow:

```
PARTITION ( DateP  RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES   
      (  
        '2015-01-01', 2015-02-01', ......2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01','2018-04-01','2018-5-01',.......
        ))
```

But, the column that I am using to partition the table includes date and time together :

`2015-01-01 00:30:00`
Do you think my partitioning approach is correct?

Answer (score 2):

5B rows  / (50 partitions x 60 Distributions) = 1.7M rows/partition on average

That's probably too many partitions, but if you have a lot of single-month queries it might be worth it. You would definitely want to [defragment your columnstores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-defragmentation?view=sql-server-2017) after load.

Comment: before I was your suggestion, I started loading the data , and I noticed it would take maybe days to load 5 billions rows , however, when I run select count(*),it will shows me the current loaded data for example  it is now  56622406, but when try to see the number of rows in each partition it shows 56 partitions and 20 rows in each, does that make sense?

Comment: Also, FYI, our data is a time series meter data, which we want to visualize it every 30 mins, so do you still think 50 partitions is too many?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with David that this is probably overkill for the number of partitions. You'll want to make sure that you have a pretty even distribution of data and with 1.7M rows or so, you'll be on the lower side. You can probably move to quarter based partitions (e.g., '2017-12-31', '2018-03-01', '2018-06-30') to get good results for query performance. This would give you 4 partitions a year since 2015 (or 20 total). So the math is:

5B rows / (20 partitions * 60 distributions) = 4.167M rows/partition.

While the number of partitions does matter for partition elimination scenarios, this is a fact table with columnstore indexes which will do an additional level of index segment elimination during query time. Over partitioning can make the situation worse rather than better.

Answer (score 0):

The guideline from Microsoft specifies that while sizing partitions, especially for columnstore indexed tables in Azure DW, the MINIMUM volume MUST be 60 million rows PER partition. Anything lower may NOT give an optimum performance. The logic to that is, there must be a MINIMUM of 1 M rows per distribution per partition. Since every partition created will internally create sixty additional distributions, the minimum works out to 60M per partition proposed to be created

Comment: Welcome. This is useful guidance. Since you’re attributing it to Microsoft, can you include a link to where they provide it? That would help make the claim more authoritative.